# Word VBA - How to edit the text in cells in tables in Header

Tags: vba, ms-word

I dont do much word work, but I need to amend the address in the headers of a batch of letters. The address is held in tables in the headers. I also need to retain the formatting.

Below is the code I have ended up with - am I getting close?

```
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim hf As Word.HeaderFooter
Dim lr As ListRow
Dim updated As Boolean
Dim tableCount As Integer
Dim t As Integer
Dim c As Cell

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(Filename:=fi.Path, ReadOnly:=False)

    For Each hf In doc.Sections(1).Headers()

    tableCount = hf.Range.Tables.Count
    For t = 1 To tableCount
        For Each c In hf.Range.Tables(t).Range.Cells
            If InStr(1, c.Range.Text, AddLOneOld) > 0 Then
                updated = True
                c.Range.Text = Replace(c.Range.Text, AddLOneOld, AddLOneNew)
            End If
            If InStr(1, c.Range.Text, AddLTwoOld) > 0 Then
                updated = True
                c.Range.Text = Replace(c.Range.Text, AddLTwoOld, AddLTwoNew)
            End If
            If InStr(1, c.Range.Text, AddLThreeOld) > 0 Then
                updated = True
                c.Range.Text = Replace(c.Range.Text, AddLThreeOld, AddLThreeNew)
            End If
        Next c
    Next t
Next hf    
If updated Then
    Set lr = filesUpdated.ListRows.Add
    lr.Range(1, 1) = fi.Path
    doc.Save
End If

doc.Close False
```

This is the nearest I have got it to go as far as running, but all it does now is produce the error
"Microsoft Excel is waiting for another application to complete an OLE action"
Thanks

Comment: Why are you involving Excel? This can all be done from within Word - most likely via a simple Find/Replace in the header(s).

Comment: It is in word - there's lots of letters so it had to be done in batches, think its working now

Comment: I used codenames in word template files: #UserAddress, #UserFirstName and so on. Then put them at proper places and replace in cycle with given values. File output seemed to be ok